# How to get all companies from DBPedia?

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

I'm new to querying DBPedia. How can I get **all** companies from http://dbpedia.org/sparql?

This query returns only 50'000 organizations:

```
SELECT DISTINCT * WHERE {?company a dbpedia-owl:Company}
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You're right that your query isn't returning all the companies.  The pattern is correct, though.  Notice that this query which only counts the companies returns 88054:

```
prefix dbpedia-owl: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>

select (count(distinct ?company) as ?count)
where {
  ?company a dbpedia-owl:Company
}
```

[SPARQL results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=prefix%20dbpedia-owl%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fontology%2F%3E%0D%0A%0D%0Aselect%20%28count%28distinct%20%3Fcompany%29%20as%20%3Fcount%29%0D%0Awhere%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%3Fcompany%20a%20dbpedia-owl%3ACompany%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&debug=on)

I think this is a limit imposed by the DBpedia SPARQL endpoint for performance reasons.  One thing that you could do is download the data and run your query locally, but that's probably a bit more work than you want.  Instead, you can order the results (it doesn't really matter *how*, so long as you always do it the same way) and use `limit` and `offset` to select within those results.  For instance:

```
prefix dbpedia-owl: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>

select ?company
where {
  ?company a dbpedia-owl:Company
}
order by ?company
limit 10
```

[SPARQL results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=prefix%20dbpedia-owl%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fontology%2F%3E%0D%0A%0D%0Aselect%20%3Fcompany%0D%0Awhere%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%3Fcompany%20a%20dbpedia-owl%3ACompany%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Aorder%20by%20%3Fcompany%0D%0Alimit%2010&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&debug=on)

```
prefix dbpedia-owl: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>

select ?company
where {
  ?company a dbpedia-owl:Company
}
order by ?company
limit 10
offset 5823
```

[SPARQL results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=prefix%20dbpedia-owl%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fontology%2F%3E%0D%0A%0D%0Aselect%20%3Fcompany%0D%0Awhere%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%3Fcompany%20a%20dbpedia-owl%3ACompany%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Aorder%20by%20%3Fcompany%0D%0Alimit%2010%0D%0Aoffset%205823&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&debug=on)

This is the general approach.  However, it still has a problem on DBpedia because of a hard limit on 40000 results. There's a documentation article which mentions this:

> #### [Working with constraints DBpedia's SPARQL endpoint MaxSortedTopRows Limits via LIMIT & OFFSET](http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/dataspace/doc/dav/wiki/Main/VirtTipsAndTricksHowToHandleBandwidthLimitExceed)
>
> The DBpedia SPARQL endpoint is configured with the following INI
>   setting:
>
> ```
> MaxSortedTopRows = 40000
> ```
>
> The setting above sets a threshold for sorted rows.

The proposed solution from that article is to use subqueries:

> To prevent the problem outlined above you can leverage the use of
>   subqueries which make better use of temporary storage associated with
>   this kind of quest. An example would take the form:
>
> ```
> SELECT ?p ?s 
> WHERE 
>   {
>     {
>       SELECT DISTINCT ?p ?s 
>       FROM <http://dbpedia.org> 
>       WHERE   
>         { 
>           ?s ?p <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Germany> 
>         } ORDER BY ASC(?p) 
>     }
>   } 
> OFFSET 50000 
> LIMIT 1000
> ```

I'm not entirely sure why this solves the problem,  perhaps it's that the endpoint can sort more than 40000 rows, as long as it doesn't have to return them all.  At any rate, it *does* work, though.  Your query would become:

```
prefix dbpedia-owl: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>

select ?company {{
  select ?company { 
    ?company a dbpedia-owl:Company
  }
  order by ?company
}} 
offset 88000
LIMIT 1000
```

Comment: However, there is a problem with sorting more than 40000 records set:
`select ?company
where {
  ?company a dbpedia-owl:Company
}
order by ?company
limit 10
offset 40000`

Comment: Getting
`Virtuoso 22023 Error SR353: Sorted TOP clause specifies more then 40010 rows to sort. Only 40000 are allowed. Either decrease the offset and/or row count or use a scrollable cursor`

Comment: @Anton Hmm… that does make things more complicated.  I think at this point, you'd want to read [Working with constraints DBpedia's SPARQL endpoint MaxSortedTopRows Limits via LIMIT & OFFSET](http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/dataspace/doc/dav/wiki/Main/VirtTipsAndTricksHowToHandleBandwidthLimitExceed), which addresses this particular issue.

Comment: Thanks! Just wanted to post this link :) Going to give it a try. I wonder if such queries return non-intersecting sets.

Comment: @Anton, I just updated my answer to show how your query can be achieved using this technique.  Looks like you'll be able to get all the companies. :)

Comment: Query # 1: `SELECT ?company
WHERE 
  {
    {
      SELECT DISTINCT ?company 
      FROM <http://dbpedia.org> 
      WHERE {
               ?company a dbpedia-owl:Company 
        } ORDER BY ASC(?company) 
    }
  } 
LIMIT 50000` and the same query with offset 50000 did the trick. Checking the uniqueness:
`$ cat sparql sparql\(1\) | wc -l
88056` To be sure:
`$ cat sparql sparql\(1\) | sort | uniq | wc -l
88055`

Answer (score 1):

Another method to get all the companies from DBpedia is to simply run with [RDFSlice](https://bitbucket.org/emarx/rdfslice) the following query:

```
SELECT * 
WHERE {
{?s a <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Person>.?s ?p ?o.} 
UNION
{?s1 a <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Person>.?o1 ?p1 ?s1.}
}
```

This has the added advantage of offering you all the triples. It takes anywhere from few minutes to several hours depending on your RAM and CPU power.