# Timeout in dbpedia sparql query. Trying with multiple fields

Tags: timeout, sparql, dbpedia, virtuoso

I am using **DBpedia SPARQL** query to get the **list of persons** with details.
I have **DBpedia dump data** which is **stored locally**. When I **query**, **virtuoso** gets **stop**.

Query -

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?dbpedia_link ?freebase_link str(?abstract) as ?abstract str(?alias) as ?alias
                        str(?birthDate) as ?birthDate str(?birthName) as ?birthName str(?birthPlace) as ?birthPlace
                        str(?label) as ?label str(?occupation) as ?occupation str(?residence) as ?residence
                        str(?spouse) as ?spouse str(?education) as ?education str(?networth) as ?networth str(?salary) as ?salary
                        str(?wikiPageID) as ?wikiPageID str(?wikiPageRevisionID) as ?wikiPageRevisionID str(?shortDescription) as ?shortDescription
                        WHERE {
                    {
                        ?dbpedia_link rdf:type dbpedia-owl:Person
                    }
                    OPTIONAL {?dbpedia_link dbpedia-owl:abstract ?abstract. }
                    OPTIONAL {?dbpedia_link dbpedia-owl:alias ?alias .}
                    OPTIONAL {?dbpedia_link dbpprop:birthDate ?birthDate .} 
                    OPTIONAL {?dbpedia_link dbpprop:birthName ?birthName .} 
                    OPTIONAL {?dbpedia_link dbpprop:birthPlace ?birthPlace .} 
                    OPTIONAL {?dbpedia_link rdfs:label ?label .} 
                    OPTIONAL {?dbpedia_link dbpprop:occupation ?occupation .}
                    OPTIONAL {?dbpedia_link dbpprop:residence ?residence .} 
                    OPTIONAL {?dbpedia_link dbpprop:spouse ?spouse .} 
                    OPTIONAL {?dbpedia_link dbpprop:education ?education .}  
                    OPTIONAL {?dbpedia_link dbpprop:networth ?networth .}  
                    OPTIONAL {?dbpedia_link dbpprop:salary ?salary .}  
                    OPTIONAL {?dbpedia_link dbpedia-owl:wikiPageID ?wikiPageID .}  
                    OPTIONAL {?dbpedia_link dbpedia-owl:wikiPageRevisionID ?wikiPageRevisionID .}
                    OPTIONAL {?dbpedia_link dbpprop:shortDescription ?shortDescription .} 
                    OPTIONAL {?dbpedia_link owl:sameAs ?freebase_link
                    FILTER regex(?freebase_link, "^http://rdf.freebase.com") .}
                }LIMIT "1"
            OFFSET "225930"
```

Any help on this?

Comment: Why don't you increase the timeout variable?

Comment: @Artemis I did. I increased the **MaxQueryExecutionTime** to **600000**. Still not succeed.

Comment: I think it has something to do with the offset then. Does it work without the offset? Can you explain what exactly you want to achieve? Do you want a person with some of these qualities after your offset?

Comment: I'm not sure whether it applies to other Virtuoso installations or not, but [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20937556/1281433) may be useful if it does have something to do with the offset. This is just a guess though;  I don't know whether it's related or not.

Comment: Also, **OFFSET** doesn't really mean anything without an **ORDER BY**.  Since the order's not specified, the query could always return the same result.

Comment: And, while Virtuoso might accept it, your query isn't legal.  The limit and offset need to be number (e.g., **LIMIT 1**, not **LIMIT "1"**), and you need parens around your projection expressions.  I.e., `select (count(?foo) as ?nFoo) { .. }`.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor: I used LIMIT and OFFSET as number. I didn't work. Finally, I changed those into string and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Thing 1 -- query edited for clarity, with a few syntax corrections.

```
SELECT  DISTINCT                               ?dbpedia_link 
                                               ?freebase_link 
                 (           str(?abstract) AS ?abstract           ) 
                 (              str(?alias) AS ?alias              )
                 (          str(?birthDate) AS ?birthDate          ) 
                 (          str(?birthName) AS ?birthName          )
                 (         str(?birthPlace) AS ?birthPlace         )
                 (              str(?label) AS ?label              )
                 (         str(?occupation) AS ?occupation         )
                 (          str(?residence) AS ?residence          )
                 (             str(?spouse) AS ?spouse             )
                 (          str(?education) AS ?education          )
                 (           str(?networth) AS ?networth           )
                 (             str(?salary) AS ?salary             )
                 (         str(?wikiPageID) AS ?wikiPageID         )
                 ( str(?wikiPageRevisionID) AS ?wikiPageRevisionID )
                 (   str(?shortDescription) AS ?shortDescription   )
  WHERE  {
                    { ?dbpedia_link          rdf:type                dbpedia-owl:Person  }
           OPTIONAL { ?dbpedia_link  dbpedia-owl:abstract            ?abstract           }
           OPTIONAL { ?dbpedia_link  dbpedia-owl:alias               ?alias              }
           OPTIONAL { ?dbpedia_link      dbpprop:birthDate           ?birthDate          } 
           OPTIONAL { ?dbpedia_link      dbpprop:birthName           ?birthName          } 
           OPTIONAL { ?dbpedia_link      dbpprop:birthPlace          ?birthPlace         } 
           OPTIONAL { ?dbpedia_link         rdfs:label               ?label              } 
           OPTIONAL { ?dbpedia_link      dbpprop:occupation          ?occupation         }
           OPTIONAL { ?dbpedia_link      dbpprop:residence           ?residence          } 
           OPTIONAL { ?dbpedia_link      dbpprop:spouse              ?spouse             } 
           OPTIONAL { ?dbpedia_link      dbpprop:education           ?education          }  
           OPTIONAL { ?dbpedia_link      dbpprop:networth            ?networth           }  
           OPTIONAL { ?dbpedia_link      dbpprop:salary              ?salary             }  
           OPTIONAL { ?dbpedia_link  dbpedia-owl:wikiPageID          ?wikiPageID         }  
           OPTIONAL { ?dbpedia_link  dbpedia-owl:wikiPageRevisionID  ?wikiPageRevisionID }
           OPTIONAL { ?dbpedia_link      dbpprop:shortDescription    ?shortDescription   } 
           OPTIONAL { ?dbpedia_link          owl:sameAs              ?freebase_link
                          FILTER regex( ?freebase_link, "^http://rdf.freebase.com" )     }
         }
  LIMIT  1
 OFFSET  225930
```

Thing 2 -- you've got undefined prefixes in there.  `dbpedia-owl`?  `dbpprop`?

Random tinkering and asking random people on the web for help *may* get you some results, but you're likely to get faster, more accurate, more relevant answers about specific products and tools by asking on forums dedicated to those products and tools, e.g., the [DBpedia discussion mailing list](https://lists.sourceforge.net/lists/listinfo/dbpedia-discussion), the [Virtuoso Users mailing list](https://lists.sourceforge.net/lists/listinfo/virtuoso-users), etc.