# How to get all organisations from DBPedia?

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

How can I get a list of all organisations from DBpedia?
By "organisation", I mean a entity of any type that is either a [organisation](http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Organisation) or any subclass of organisation.

I found the question  [How to get all companies from DBPedia?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20937556/how-to-get-all-companies-from-dbpedia) but this doesn't work in the current DBpedia SPARQL web version and I wasn't able to adapt the query.

Comment: Would be could to see the query that you tried. And what "does not work" means - returned nothing, an incomplete result, the wrong result...

Comment: In the query of your link, the prefix `dbpedia-owl` is now different `dbo`

Comment: Please note that I have updated my answer: the filter was not in the right place.

Comment: I've updated the answer to [How to get all companies from DBPedia?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20937556/how-to-get-all-companies-from-dbpedia) to include the appropriate prefix definition.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To simply get all resources that are an instance of `dbo:Organization` or its subclass:

```
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
SELECT DISTINCT ?org { ?org a/rdfs:subClassOf* dbo:Organisation . }
```

However, as the question you linked shows, DBpedia has a cap on how many results are returned. So, as in the answer to said question, you can use a subquery with `LIMIT` and `OFFSET` to get all the results in chunks:

```
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
SELECT ?org {
  SELECT DISTINCT ?org {
    ?org a/rdfs:subClassOf* dbo:Organisation .
 } ORDER BY ?org
}
LIMIT 10000 OFFSET 0
```

This would get you the first 10000 results. To get the next 10000, just add 10000 to the offset: `LIMIT 10000 OFFSET 10000`. Then, the next 10000 with `OFFSET 20000`, and so on.

Comment: when I read your answer, I first thought that indeed using `*` (zero or more) is more efficient, but only more efficient way. But in fact it gives more results than `a|a/rdfs:subClassOf+`. How would you explain that?

Comment: I get the same amount of results with count disctinct (350113).

Comment: Indeed, but using it in the query I suggested, it is 350113 with |+ and 386676 with*. Any idea why?

Comment: I've no idea why they differ. I don't think they should, tho.

Comment: `+` means instances of subclasses or descendants of `dbo:Organization`, while `*` also includes the instances that are only asserted to the `dbo:Organisation`.

Comment: @AKSW Yes, but the property paths in question are `a|a/rdfs:subClassOf+` vs. `a/rdfs:subClassOf*`, which are equal if I'm not mistaken.

Answer (score 3):

You can get all organisations with a query like this, giving you English label and Wikipedia page for those resources that have it:

```
PREFIX  rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX    o: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
PREFIX foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>

SELECT DISTINCT   ?orgURI ?orgName ?Wikipedia_page

WHERE {
           ?orgURI  a                  o:Organisation .

OPTIONAL { ?orgURI  rdfs:label         ?orgName . 
                    FILTER (lang(?orgName) = "en") }

OPTIONAL { ?orgURI  ^foaf:primaryTopic ?Wikipedia_page }

}

ORDER BY ?orgName
```

This will currently return 350033 results for those resources that are classified as `http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Organisation`.

To get also the members of subclasses of `http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Organisation`, you can change the first pattern by turning the property into a property path going though zero or more `rdfs:subClassOf`:

```
?orgURI  a/rdfs:subClassOf*  o:Organisation
```