# Why does dbpedia sparql query not show all the results?

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

I am building a NED system for assignment. To find the candidate entities out of all wikipedia entities that can be linked name mentions I am planning to use dbpedia. But dbpedia query is not showing all pages.

For example an entity dbpedia/pages/Jaguar is shown as having rdf:type owl:Thing but when I run following query the results do not include Jaguar.

```
    SELECT ?subject WHERE {
    ?subject rdf:type owl:Thing}
```

Is it because it filters out some results automatically if there are too many results? What is the solution?

Comment: The reason is quite obvious. The DBpedia endpoint is a free, shared service, thus, there is a default limit of 10000.

Comment: You can load the whole DBpedia dataset into your own hosted triple store and there indeed you can increase the resultset size or even disable it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get all companies from DBPedia?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20937556/how-to-get-all-companies-from-dbpedia)

Comment: If you count (this time the query will work), you'll see that there are about 5mln things currently in DBpedia.